# How to set that when installed will not show 'WIndows security' message? by c#

Tags: c#

How to set that when installed drivers will not show 'WIndows security' message
"windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software"

Answer (score 1):

You will need to **buy** a certificate from an official authority, then **sign** your application with this certificate.

Read [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/che5h906.aspx) on signing.

See [here](http://www.sslshopper.com/microsoft-authenticode-certificates.html) to get some ideas on the prices.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will always show the UAC prompt as part of elevation. If you want to make the message identify yourself as the supplier of the software then you will need to by a digital certificate with which to sign your install package. You will need to undergo a degree of vetting in order to obtain a certificate.